# Format Python Floating Point Numbers like Java does

Tags: java, python, printf

My program consists of a Java and a Python component and I want Python to format floating point numbers exactly in the same way as Java does by default.

Java:

```
    float number1 = (float) Math.PI;
    float number2 = (float) Math.PI / 1000f;
    float number3 = (float) Math.PI / 10000f;
    float number4 = (float) Math.PI / 100000f;
    float number5 = (float) (int)(Math.PI * 1000000f) / 1000000f / 100000f;

    System.out.println(number1); // prints 3.1415927
    System.out.println(number2); // prints 0.0031415927
    System.out.println(number3); // prints 3.1415926E-4
    System.out.println(number4); // prints 3.1415926E-5
    System.out.println(number5); // prints 3.141592E-5
```

How to get the same output in Python?

First attempts in Python:

```
import math

number1 = float(math.pi)
number2 = float(math.pi / 1000)
number3 = float(math.pi / 10000)
number4 = float(math.pi / 100000)
number5 = float(int(math.pi * 1000000) / 1000000 / 100000)

print(number1) # prints 3.141592653589793
print(number2) # prints 0.0031415926535897933
print(number3) # prints 0.0003141592653589793
print(number4) # prints 3.141592653589793e-05
print(number5) # prints 3.141592e-05

print("{:8e}".format(number1)) # prints 3.141593e+00
print("{:8e}".format(number2)) # prints 3.141593e-03
print("{:8e}".format(number3)) # prints 3.141593e-04
print("{:8e}".format(number4)) # prints 3.141593e-05
print("{:8e}".format(number5)) # prints 3.141592e-05
```

Comment: For completion can you include what the java output for different values is?

Comment: I just added the output for different test cases

Answer (score 3):

Your formatting syntax is incorrect. Do this instead

```
print("{:.15f}".format(math.pi))
```

or the old fashioned way

```
print("%.15f" % (math.pi))
```

Comment: I just added further test cases to the question

Comment: What means exactly `.15f`? Number of decimals? And, Why you said the `%` is the **old fashioned way**? Is worst? I always use %...

Comment: @EnderLook the first one is the more pythonic way. It was recommended for Python3 and above. IMO though.

Comment: Is it faster? Sorry for asking you.

Comment: @EnderLook I don't think it is faster, but I am not sure. I mostly answer in Java, and thus, not aware of this detail in Python :)